# Hover effect not applying to anchor tag inside a bootstrap dropdown menu?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hey everyone I am facing this issue and I don't seem to find any solution. Actually I have created a bootstrap drop-down menu given below.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
   <li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
   <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1
        <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu drop-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
</ul>
```

And I have applied the CSS given below.

```
.drop-menu a:hover{background-color:red!important;}
```

But the background color is still the default one(of bootstrap) when I take the mouse over the anchor tag placed inside the drop down menu

Answer (score 0):

you're creating the hover over only the link, in this case the `<a>` tag. Try removing the `<a>` tag and put the hover over the full menu-item. example code.

```
ul.dropdown-menu li:hover {
 background-color:red!important;
}
```

If you really want the background only behind the link then use the following css.

```
ul.dropdown-menu li a:hover {
 background-color:red!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.menu li a:hover{
  background-color:red!important;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
   <li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
   <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1
        <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu drop-menu menu">
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
.nav>.drop-menu>li>a:hover
{
  background-color:red;
  display:block:
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

Actually bootstrap adds background-image to a tag. To remove it I added the following code to existing css.

```
.drop-menu a:hover{background-color:red!important; background-image:none!important;}
```